# Log.wtf() displays as Log.e() in Android Studio 2.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat, android-studio-2.0

I have styled my LogCat levels using Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & fonts -> Android Logcat, but all of a sudden when I do `Log.wtf()` it displays with the style set for the `Error` level, not `Assert` like it used to be?

Comment: Just curious :/ why does it matter!

Comment: Because it makes it way easier to spot certain log outputs than if they all look the same. Especially since Android Studio Logcat doesn't format the output into columns like Eclipse used to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On API 23, `Log.wtf()` no longer creates a log of `ASSERT` level, but rather `ERROR` level.

However, one can still get the style for the `ASSERT` level by using

```
Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "TAG", "Message");
```

on API 23.

Answer (score 0):

The framework team downgraded WTF ( What a Terrible Failure ) from an Assert to an Error

```
 static int wtf(int logId, String tag, String msg, Throwable tr, boolean localStack,
        boolean system) {
    TerribleFailure what = new TerribleFailure(msg, tr);
    // Only mark this as ERROR, do not use ASSERT since that should be
    // reserved for cases where the system is guaranteed to abort.
    // The onTerribleFailure call does not always cause a crash.
    int bytes = println_native(logId, ERROR, tag, msg + '\n'
            + getStackTraceString(localStack ? what : tr));
    sWtfHandler.onTerribleFailure(tag, what, system);
    return bytes;
}
```

[link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java#292)

In android studio 2.0  it works "as Intended".

If you want to see WTF logs showed ad assert, run your application on an older device (Api << 23)

Try also to target your app not over Api 19